# Is the front-page.php template reserved in wordpress twenty twelve theme?

Tags: child-theme, theme-twenty-twelve

I'm writing my first twenty twelve child theme and came across (what I think) is a strange quirk.

I modified front-page.php to have a slider using sliderjs, afterwards I decided I did not want to use this as a front page template, so I'd much prefer to call it something else for a different page.

To my surprise, the moment I renamed front-page.php to text-carousel.php and changed the Template Name in the docblock to something else the page changes from displaying my content in full width and the widgets below to a 2 column version similar to my blog, but with the widgets assigned to front-page.

So, is front-page.php a reserved template in twenty twelve? is it possible to duplicate its look and feel into a different template?

For reference here's my code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Text Carousel Page Template
 *
 * Description: A page template that provides a key component of WordPress as a CMS
 * by meeting the need for a carefully crafted introductory page. The front page template
 * in Twenty Twelve consists of a page content area for adding text, images, video --
 * anything you'd like -- followed by front-page-only widgets in one or two columns.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twelve
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */

get_header('nonav'); ?>

<div id="primary" class="site-content">
    <div id="content" role="main">
        <div id="example">
            <div id="slides">
                <div class="slides_container">
        <?php 
        $args = array(
                        'posts_per_page'  => 5,
                        'orderby'         => 'post_date',
                        'order'           => 'DESC',
                        'post_type'       => 'post',
                        'post_status'     => 'publish',
                        'suppress_filters' => true );

                    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
                    foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
                        <div class="slide">
                          <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                          <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                          <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="link">Leer articulo</a></p>
                        </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div><!-- .slides_container -->
            </div><!-- #slides -->
        </div><!-- #example -->

    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
<?php get_sidebar( 'front' ); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

It works fine if the file is called twentytwelve/page-templates/front-page.php with **Template Name: Template Name: Front Page Template**, but it goes 2 column as twentytwelve/page-templates/text-carousel.php with **Template Name: Text Carousel Page Template**

I had posted this question in stackoverflow, but it didn't seem to be getting too much success so I decided to open an account here and move it across.

Comment: It is not done to post your question on multiple SE sites. Please remove it here or there. You could also have asked a moderator to migrate your question, which would've been the best.

Comment: Wow... you posted on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296201/is-the-front-page-php-template-reserved-in-wordpress-twenty-twelve-theme) about 20 minutes before you posted here.

Comment: I thought I had deleted that one, I moved it across because I figured this site is more in line with the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same problem and finally figured it out. You have to go into `functions.php` line 390 -

```
if ( is_page_template( 'page-templates/front-page.php' ) ) {
```

copy and paste this section of code and rename it to the file name you have chosen for your template.

Then you have to alter all the CSS that references `.template-front-page` to whatever you called your template. (I made it easy and just added to the file name - you could call it template-front-page-carousel for example)

A little tweaking here and there and two identical templates - no you can change the content to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress includes a class to the page template in the `<body>` tag of the page. If you know how to use CSS you can just style the template to look exactly like the `front-page.php` by using this class. The class would look something like `.page-template-text-carousel-page-template-php`.

It wouldn't take very long to add some styles to change the layout to whatever you like.

Comment: Refer to [style.css](http://themes.svn.wordpress.org/twentytwelve/1.1.1/style.css). The section is `/* =Front page template */`, and the CSS selector is the `.template-front-page` body class.

Comment: There you go just copy those styles for your page template and your done.  Thanks Chip

Comment: @ChipBennett this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`front-page.php` is a reserved template in *WordPress*, not just Twenty Twelve. The templating system is implemented and enforced by the WordPress core not by any particular theme.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Template_Files_List

Comment: So how can I get a page that overall gets the same style as this one, but with customized content different from front-page.php?

Comment: With a custom template, you need to create a page from the backend and assign that page to the template. Did you do that?

Comment: yes, when I assign it the front-page template it looks great, as soon as I assign it to the other template (which is a clone of the front page template with a diff name) it creates a sidebar with the widgets instead of keeping them at the bottom